# Reset Password user flow is not work in Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, ionic4, customization, azure-authentication

I have tried to make Azure B2C authentication by using following link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows and Sign In page is working fine but i am unable to redirect to reset password page when clicking "Forgot Password?" option from Sign In page.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! Can you edit your question to add more detail on what doesn't work and how you configure it?

Answer (score 0):

A sign-up or sign-in user flow with local accounts includes a [Forgot password?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-overview#linking-user-flows) link on the first page of the experience. Clicking this link doesn't automatically trigger a password reset user flow.

Your application needs to handle this error code by running a specific user flow that resets the password. To see an example, take a look at a simple ASP.NET sample that demonstrates the linking of user flows.